# failed to import bridging header swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7.3

I was trying to use SocketIO and Alamofire using cocoapods and started facing this issue. Earlier I added these libraries manually which was working fine.[image]

Answer (score 0):

goto Project->Bulid Setting->Objective-C Bridging Header  set "Header.h"... but full path insert

your header file into project group  the full path... Like project group name is "XYZ",header file name "Header.h"..set "XYZ/Hrader.h" to Objective-C Bridging Header

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. I tried this already but its not working.

Comment: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Reachability/Reachability.swift use this class in swift

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 simple steps to follow,

1. Add a new Header file into project, using File - > New -> File -> iOS -> Source -> Header File.
2. Name the class `'your-project-name-Bridging-Header.h'`

   and press continue to save the file.
3. Go to Build Settings -> Objective-C Bridging Header and set as `‘your-project-name-Bridging-Header.h’`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `use_frameworks` flag of Cocoapods (which you probably are, since you are using Swift), you have to import like this `#import <Reachability/Reachability.h>`.

A more general statement would be `#import <MODULE/FILE>`.